# Java Dynammic bean / shared between Users

Tags: java, spring

I have java web application, that is being used by multiple users. By users I mean people that actually connect to application and do stuff with it.

Every user can edit a schema, that has it's ID. At the moment, multiple users can edit same schema at the same time. I want to fix that, without using a database/table.

What I tried so far:

There's an EDIT button, that users click to edit certain schema. When they click it, a method is triggered.

```
protected SessionLockModSchema sessionLockModSchema = new SessionLockModSchema();
protected Model model; //schema model object
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    //button logic goes here
}
```

I figured I might create a bean with schema ID, when this method is triggered.

```
protected SessionLockModSchema sessionLockModSchema = new SessionLockModSchema();
protected Model model;
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    //button logic goes here
    this.sessionLockModSchema.lockSchema(model);
}
```

When I have this bean created, all that I need to do is check if it exists, for the next user.

```
protected Model model;
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    if(!this.sessionLockModSchema.isSchemaLocked(model){
        //button logic goes here
        this.sessionLockModSchema.lockSchema(model);
    }
}
```

In theory this sounded good to me, edit button wouldn't trigger if there was a bean created with that schema. But bean is not created (or at least only one user can access it). Here's sessionLockModSchema class:

```
public class SessionLockModSchema{

    ApplicationContext context;
    GenericApplicationContext ctx; 

    public SessionLockModSchema(){
        if(ctx == null){
            this.ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
        }
    }

    public void lockSchema(Model model){
        String beanName = "model-"+model.getId();

        BeanDefinitionBuilder bDBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder .rootBeanDefinition(String.class);
        bDBuilder.setScope("prototype");
        this.ctx.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, bDBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
        //appcontext.close();
    }

    public boolean isSchemaLocked(Model model){
        String beanName = "model-"+model.getId();
        Object objectRef = null;
        try{
            //ctx.refresh();
            objectRef = this.ctx.getBean(beanName); 
        }catch(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e){
            // TODO:
        }catch(IllegalStateException e){
            // TODO:
        }
        boolean isLocked;
        if(objectRef == null){
            isLocked = false;
        }else{
            isLocked = true;
        }
        return isLocked;

    }
}
```

To clarify my question, I get IllegalStateException saying that beanFactory must be refreshed, if I do however refresh (commented ctx.refresh), I get that no such bean exists. Any advices on this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like that (I don't see why you would need spring managed beans here):

```
public enum SessionLockModSchema {
    INSTANCE;

    private final Set<String> lockedModels = new HashSet<>;

    public void lockSchema(Model model){
        synchronized(lockedModels) {
            lockedModels.add("" + model.getId());
        }
    }

    public void unlockSchema(Model model){
        synchronized(lockedModels) {
            lockedModels.remove("" + model.getId());
        }
    }


    public void isSchemaLocked(Model model){
        synchronized(lockedModels) {
            return lockedModels.contains("" + model.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

usage (something like that):

```
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    if (SessionLockModSchema.INSTANCE.isLocked(model) {
        try {
            SessionLockModSchema.INSTANCE.lockSchema(model);
            // do something with "model"
        } finally {
            SessionLockModSchema.INSTANCE.unlockSchema(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this is very similar to what I had at the start, but I'm not very familiar with bean creation (outside config.xml file) and decided that spring would make my life easier...I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Hm, I think you either misunderstood me, Or I misunderstood you. Your method created bean is accessible only for one user (I think session scope), other logged in user can't see it. WHat I need is a bean with data (say lockedModels) that could be accessed at application scope. One user creates bean, other users (when logged in) can access that bean and so on. By the way, I get a strange error, [tomcat log here](http://codepad.org/6eFQbxNM)

Comment: Maybe you should share more of your code, I will edit my answer to to it without spring

Comment: There's nothing to share really, that's all. This code is part of [activiti explorer](http://activiti.org/).

Comment: This works after all, I was just using same browser to simulate 2 users, and that doesn't work. Thanks for the help.